# Getting Code review responses for TFS check in policy

Tags: c#, visual-studio, tfs

I am currently creating custom TFS Check in Policy. I would like to be able to allow check in only if some constraints regarding TFS review are satisfied (let's say 3x looks good, no with comments etc.).

I have managed to get Code review request pretty easily, iterating through PendingCheckin.WorkItems.CheckedWorkItems, but I struggle to get responses for this review. I know there is a way, running Query on WorkItemStore, but isn't there any easier solution for my problem?

Thanks

Comment: Yep, did it, thanks. Marked your answer as the best one. 

For anyone interested, the policy is open sourced under Apache 2.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is already a Code Review Checkin Policy available at the website below, you can use it directly:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ColinD.ColinsALMCheckinPoliciesVS2017

The policy is configurable to allow you to specify:

- The source control path(s) that will trigger the Code Review check
- That the policy will fail if the Code Review Request is not Closed
- That the policy will fail if any response result is 'Needs Work'
- That the policy will pass if all response results are 'Looks Good' or

  - that the policy will pass if all response results are 'Looks Good' or
    'With Comments'
  - 'None' means the policy will pass if a Code Review is logged,
    irrespective of state or results
- That the policy must only check the most recent Code Review Request

Comment: If I have 50 developers am I need to install the extension in each developer PC?
Who have the permissions to enable/disable the policy?